# How to use pandas for comparisons only of a part of a variable?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to compare codes in two dataframes. I'm using Python 3 and pandas

In the first base the codes always have 18 digits:

```
dividas_dep = pd.read_csv("dividas_deputados_ajustado_csv.csv",sep=';',encoding = 'latin_1')

dividas_dep.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 106 entries, 0 to 105
Data columns (total 10 columns):
CPF_Deputado                  106 non-null object
CPF_limpo                     106 non-null int64
Nome_Deputado                 106 non-null object
Vinculo                       106 non-null object
CNPJ_Devedor                  106 non-null object
CNPJ_limpo                    106 non-null int64
Nome_Devedor                  106 non-null object
Valores_situacao_Irregular    65 non-null object
Valores_situacao_Regular      52 non-null object
Total_Devido                  106 non-null object
dtypes: int64(2), object(8)
memory usage: 8.4+ KB
```

The column to compare in this first base ("CNPJ_Devedor") has these examples: 17.080.201/0001-49, 76.205.723/0001-99, 04.885.828/0001-25...

And in the second base, the codes always have 10 digits:

```
funrural = pd.read_excel('DEVEDORES FUNRURAL ATUALIZADO PGFN.xlsx')

funrural.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 8130 entries, 0 to 8129
Data columns (total 14 columns):
PSFN_PGFN               8129 non-null object
Regiao                  8129 non-null object
CNPJ_CEI_Tipo           8129 non-null object
CNPJ_Raiz               8129 non-null object
Razao_Social            8130 non-null object
Valor_principal         8130 non-null float64
Valor_TR_IPC_Poup       8130 non-null float64
Valor_Juros             8130 non-null float64
Valor_SELIC             8130 non-null float64
Valor_Encargo           8130 non-null float64
Valor_Multa_Oficio      8130 non-null float64
Valor_Selic_M_Oficio    8130 non-null float64
Vl_Multa_Mora           8130 non-null float64
Vl_Tot_Credito          8130 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(9), object(5)
memory usage: 889.3+ KB
```

The column to compare in this second base ("CNPJ_Raiz") has these examples: 04.244.173, 05.006.407, 03.632.132...

The codes "CNPJ_Devedor" and "CNPJ_Raiz" are related in tax legislation, but I can not make a simple merge like this:

```
compara1 = pd.merge(dividas_dep, funrural, left_on='CNPJ_Devedor', right_on='CNPJ_Raiz')
```

What I need to do is compare only the first 10 digits of "CNPJ_Devedor" with the code "CNPJ_Raiz" (example, in "17.080.201/0001-49" use only "17.080.201")

Is there any way to do this in Python? Or should I edit the original dataframe file, dividas_dep (dividas_deputados_ajustado_csv.csv), to create a new column with only the first 10 digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare the slice of the first 10 string elements with `.str.slice(None, 10)`:

```
dividas_dep["CNPJ_Devedor"].str.slice(None, 10) == funrural["CNPJ_Raiz"]
```

Example:

```
>>> dividas_dep = pd.DataFrame({"CNPJ_Devedor": ['17.080.201/0001-49', '76.205.723/0001-99', '04.885.828/0001-25']})
>>> funrural = pd.DataFrame({"CNPJ_Raiz": ['17.080.201', '04.244.173', '05.006.407']})
>>> dividas_dep["CNPJ_Devedor"].str.slice(None, 10) == funrural["CNPJ_Raiz"]
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

You can use the result to create a new dataframe:

```
res = dividas_dep["CNPJ_Devedor"].str.slice(None, 10) == funrural["CNPJ_Raiz"]
funrural[res]
```

Comment: Thank you
I tried to iterate to read the two databases and compare using your example, but it gave error. Should I post a new question?

Comment: Don't iterate. Work on the whole dataframes.

Comment: But I need to generate a new dataframe from the comparison